# salt-manage bootstrap -- Could not resolve hostname

Tags: saltstack

I run my salt-minion and salt-stack on a single machine with its hostname as `HOSTNAME`. When salt-minion's key get accepted by the salt-master service, it appends `localdomain` to the minion's hostname.
So, it looks like this,

```
Accepted Keys:
sk-box.localdomain
```

I expect,

```
Accepted Keys:
sk-box
```

And when i try to bootstrap with the listed name using the command `salt-run manage.bootstrap hosts='sk-box.localdomain'`, it throws error as,

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

Comment: Has your question been answered?  Is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: @Dan, thanks for your msg... i will take 2 more days to check it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I configure on all my minions before bootstrapping salt is the minion id.

This problem is so common that Salt Stack added an option to [Salt Bootstrap](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/salt_bootstrap.html#command-line-options) to set the minion id at install time:

> -i  Pass the salt-minion id. This will be stored under /etc/salt/minion_id

If you aren't using bootstrap.sh to install you can set the minion id in either of these files BEFORE starting or installing salt-minion:

1. /etc/salt/minion.d/local.conf
2. /etc/salt/minion_id

I then usually add states in the highstate run that configure /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/hostname, /etc/domainname, and /etc/hosts based on `grains['id']`